# Why is .class file not executing? It's getting created when I use java compiler

Tags: java, javac

Is it because of environment variables? I am getting the following messages.

> C:\Users\Manas Sharma\Desktop\java>javac fjp.java
>
> C:\Users\Manas Sharma\Desktop\java>java fjp.class Error: Could not
>   find or load main class fjp.class

```
import java.lang.*;
class fjp{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: just a note you don't need that import `import java.lang.*;`

Comment: your command is wrong which should be `C:\Users\Manas Sharma\Desktop\java>java fjp`

Comment: @Deadpool i tried that too still same error

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
java -classpath . fjp
```